# Getting float without Math tool in Apache Velocity

Tags: velocity

I have a situation where I need to capture the full decimal output of a calculation in Velocity, however, I do not have access to Math (MathTool) within the solution I'm dealing with and cannot add it in.

Is there some way to perform division and capture the portion after the decimal up to 3 places without using velocities "Math" library?

Basically, my goal is this:

1. Perform division such as 4 / 3 which results in 1.3333333333
2. Retain 2 places after the decimal so the final result is 1.33
3. Have the result 1.33 be a type of double so you can perform further math arithmetic operations on it (can't just format as string, unless we can covert it back to double)

I am pretty new to Velocity so any direction here would be awesome.

Thanks!
Bob

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. And you can gather the rounding code in a macro as follow:

```
#macro(round $n)
  #set($n = $n * 100)
  #set($n = $n.intValue() / 100.0)
#end

#set($n = 4.0/3.0)
before roundering: $n
#round($n)
after roundering: $n ($n.class.name)
```

This results in:

```
before roundering: 1.3333333333333333
after roundering: 1.33 (java.lang.Double)
```